# Is it possible to procure an Amazon S3 instance on dedicated physical hardware?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The title pretty much says it all. We're looking for a simple way to set up an SFTP site – but, for security reasons, it can't live on hardware that's shared with other clients.

Does Amazon offer S3 instances that live on dedicated hardware? I've looked on their site, and I see that you can get dedicated *EC2* instances (for an arm an a leg) – but I couldn't find anything about dedicated S3 instances.

Thanks!

Comment: S3 doesn't offer instances at all. S3 is just object storage.

Comment: S3 doesn't have an FTP interface. If you want SFTP hosted in AWS you need to set up an EC2 instance.

Comment: I bet that Amazon has sales-support experts that can answer this question perfectly for you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get an S3 *instance* of any kind - S3 is object (file) storage, and the only container is a *bucket* - any backing hardware is abstracted away as S3 is not a compute platform, just storage. Think of it as a "network-drive-as-a-service" of sorts.

Also S3 does not support SFTP (or any protocol other than HTTP for that matter). You can read more about how to expose an S3 bucket via SFTP in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23939179/215379) (TL;DR - use an EC2 instance).

Answer (score 1):

You could run your own S3-compatible system with [minio](https://minio.io/).

> ### Deploy Amazon S3 compatible object storage server in seconds
>
> Use official Minio Docker image to launch your own Amazon S3 compatible object storage server in few seconds. Use Minio to create private Docker registries or store application data (photos, videos, DB backups, logs).
>
> ### Consistent deployment across multi-cloud environments
>
> Uniform, repeatable deployments across public and private clouds.
>
> ### Provide object storage API access to Docker volumes
>
> Minio adds Amazon S3 compatible object storage to existing Docker volumes. Attach Docker volumes to Minio containers and access data with REST API.
>
> ### Orchestrate storage cluster with Docker Swarm
>
> Launch as many Minio instances to cater to ever growing storage needs, and use Docker Swarm to orchestrate multi-tenant Minio instances across racks of servers.

[SwiftStack](https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/admin/middleware/s3_middleware.html) provides a commercial choice for you as well.

Comment: Of course, none of these will offer SFTP.

Comment: It sounds like they want to base this on S3-compatible technology and others have explained how to do SFTP on top of S3 here already.